# Removing path from system's PATH within a batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to remove a variable path from the **system's** `PATH` environment variable from within a batch script.

For example, if `MY_DIR=C:\MyDir`, I want to remove `MY_DIR` from `PATH`.

I've tried

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call setx /M PATH %%PATH:%MY_DIR%=%%
```

But it fails with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "_path="
for %%# in ("%path:;=";"%") do (
    echo %%#
  if /i "%%~#" neq  "C:\Docker" (
    set "_path=!_path!;%%~#"
  )
)

set "path=%_path%"
echo %path%
endlocal
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Doesn't seem to change PATH at all :(

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't change the system's `PATH`. It only changes `PATH` locally. Note that we should use `setx /M` for setting a system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set newpath=!path:%MY_DIR%=!
setx path %newpath% /M
```

should do the trick, although only partially tested

Edit: after some testing, it turned out

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 set newpath=!path:%MY_DIR%=!
 set newpath=%newpath:;;=;%
 setx path %newpath% >nul
```

is actually the way to do it

Comment: this will leave two adjacent delimiters `;` in the returned path, right?

Comment: if you want to prevent it from doing that, just change the third line to `set newpath=!path:%MY_DIR%;=!` ,so the `;` after MY_DIR will get removed

Comment: ...but only if `%MY_DIR%` is not the last part of `%PATH%`; I'd rather replace `;;` by `;` in a separate step, so insert `set newpath=%newpath:;;=;%` between line 3 and 4...

Comment: I'm still getting 
'ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).' :(

Comment: ok, deleting the `/M`in line four worked for me, i'm going to edit/update my post regarding the changes discussed above

Comment: @hammockdude - Thanks for that but it still doesn't work :(.
I'm getting the same error message. Note that I want to remove `MY_DIR` from the system's path and not the user's. So we need to add the `/M` flag to `setx`.

Comment: does yout MYDIR consist of any strange characters (like ^; &" and so on)? Are you using my code encased in a for-loop? because that would make everything much more complicated (and would also explain the error messages). Other than that i'm running out of ideas why it is workin for me, but not working for you..

Comment: @hammockdude Thanks for the help. No, I don't have any strange characters in `MY_DIR`. It is just a simple directory path in the system.